# How would I say ‘act accordingly’ in latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

How would I say ‘act accordingly’ in Latin? This would be an instruction to act in a manner appropriate to circumstance.

Answer (score 3):

To a single person:

> *ita te geres.*
>
> 'You will conduct yourself accordingly.'

To a group:

> *ita vos geretis.*
>
> 'You will conduct yourselves accordingly.'

If you wish to be a little less forceful:

> *ita te geras. / ita vos geratis.*
>
> 'Please conduct yourself / yourselves accordingly.'

Or if you wish to be a little more forceful:

> *ita te gerito. / ita vos geritote.*
>
> 'You shall conduct yourself / yourselves accordingly.'

Comment: Many thanks, that is incredibly helpful. I’m assuming that this would work as a motto on a cost of arms or family crest?

Comment: @Luke I've just re-read your question and realized I may have misinterpreted your use of *accordingly.* Do you mean 'in the manner described' (e.g., *we must be polite; act accordingly.*) or 'in an appropriate manner' (e.g., *every circumstance is different; act accordingly.*)?

Comment: Apologies, the website won’t allow further comment. To clarify, I meant the latter. It would be act accordingly - Every circumstance is different - act accordingly. The instruction to act in a manner particular to the situation. Alter your behaviour accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: @Luke In that case I would replace *ita* 'thus' with *apte* 'suitably'. For a coat of arms the singular imperative is normal, so *apte te ger,* although this sounds pretty ugly. I think *apte age* would sound much better while retaining the meaning!

Comment: Did you mean  apte te gere? This is now not so ugly and a good motto. It was probably a lapsus calami on your part.